# Kivy, RecycleView Add and Delete rows

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to better understand how the RecycleView functions. Seems like only practical examples will teach me. Docs aren't helping. Kindly have a look at my current screen in the pic below.

[image: RV Screenshot]

Now following are what I'm trying to achieve.

1. Add/Remove new rows to/from the list.
2. The first column sl/no should maintain the order even after deleting from in between.
3. How to achieve 'sort' function? Is it by taking the data into python and do the sort and then update that to the RV again ?

Please find the both .py and .kv codes below.

## rv_main.py

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'gl'
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior, RecycleBoxLayout):

    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
class RecycleViewRow(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''

    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    slno    = StringProperty('')
    typ     = StringProperty('')

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(RecycleViewRow, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(RecycleViewRow, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''

        self.selected = is_selected

        if is_selected:
            pass
        else:
            pass

    def delete_row(self,rv, index, is_selected):
        if is_selected:
            rv.data.pop(index)
            rv.layout_manager.clear_selection()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #fetch data from the database
        self.data = [{'slno': str(x+1),'typ': 'default'} for x in range(4)]

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

class DataTable(BoxLayout):

    def addRow(self):
        pass

    def removeRow(self):
        pass

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

class RvMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return DataTable()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RvMainApp().run()
```

## rvmain.kv

```
#: kivy 1.11.0

<RecycleViewRow>:
    id: rv
    slno: ""
    typ: ""

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint: 1.0, 1.0

    Label:
        text: root.slno
        size_hint_x : 1.0

    Label:
        text: root.typ
        size_hint_x : 1.0

#----------------------------------------------------------------
<RV>:
    id : rv
    viewclass: 'RecycleViewRow'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(40)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'

#----------------------------------------------------------------
<DataTable>:
    orientation : 'vertical'

    Button:

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
        RV:
        Button:

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Add"
            on_release: rv.data.append({"slno": "?", "typ": 'default'})

        Button:
            text: "Remove"
            on_release:
```

Answer (score 1):

You edit the data list of the recycleview. The data will be sorted as it is sorted in that list.
So here is an example of the add remove feature:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


KV = '''

<Row@BoxLayout>:
    ind: 1
    Button:
        text: str(root.ind)
    Button:
        text: "default"

BoxLayout:
    ind: 1
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
        RecycleView:
            id: rv
            data: [{"text":"first","ind":1}]

            viewclass: 'Row'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
        Button
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Add"
            on_release:
                root.ind += 1
                rv.data.append({"ind": root.ind})
        Button:
            text: "Remove"
            on_release:
                root.ind = root.ind - 1 if root.ind > 0 else 0
                if len(rv.data): rv.data.pop(-1)

'''



class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.root


Test().run()
```

And here is an example on how to sort the data list by some key. In this case ind.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
RecycleView:
    viewclass: 'Label'
    data: sorted([{"text":"!", "ind":3},{"text":"world", "ind":2},{"text":"hello", "ind":1}], key=lambda k: k["ind"])
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        id: layout
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
'''

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Still I'm not able to use that into my structure. The data for the RV is not being set in KV file instead it's been called in from a db in python. Hence in my example I followed that structure which I've implemented in my actual program. 

I tried by calling the db data in the build function and saved it into a variable. Later in the kv file i tried to feed that value into RecycleView data but it's not accepting. Can you kindly show how to implement it in the pattern which I've used in my example ?

Comment: And moreover, those buttons eventhough it's in the same screen but it's inside another float layout and not inside the same box layout. (Was doubting if that would affect the calling of the id 'rv' assigned to the recycleview.)

Comment: I've updated the KV file in my original question. It says rv not recognized when invoked from add button.